# How to store a reference to an array element?

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to store a reference to an array element and modify the array element using the reference.

Example Code:

```
var myArray : [String] = ["foo"]
var element = myArray.first!
element.append("bar")
print(myArray.first!)
```

Expected Output:

```
> foobar
```

Actual Output:

```
> foo
```

My expectation was that `first` would return a reference to the array element. Instead, Swift returns a copy of the element, meaning the array element doesn't get modified.

Is there a way to store a reference to an array element using Swift arrays?

Comment: [this](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift's `String` is a value type, so it returns a copy not a reference, if you want to get a reference you should use `NSString` not `String`.

Comment: I used `String` for the sake of example. In the actual code, I am using a custom class.

Comment: @user3225395 I’d suggest making an example that doesn’t use a value type in your question.

Comment: I debugged my code, and I realized the bug is due to another piece of code that I overlooked. I'll mark this as answered, since it solves the example I gave.

Comment: Although the OP chose an example with a value data type, this does not answer the question "How to store a reference to an array element?"